# Whether a given context-free language is regular

Tags: finite-automata, regular-language

Is it Decidable whether:

1. A given grammar is Context free?
2. A given recursive language is Context free?
3. A given context free language is regular?

Comment: Your answer: sure why not.

Comment: this isnt exactly a homework. I was reading about decidability and these questions came to my mind.

Comment: yeah... but people who camp the homework section will be able to help. Although this question is probably better suited for cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Rook - Homework tag should not be used anyway. It’s obsolete and is in the process of being removed.

Answer (score 3):

A given grammer can give us the language and using the language and Pumping Lemma , we can easily decide if the given grammer is Context free

By using Greibach's theorem, we can show that it is undecidable whether context-free language is regualr or not..

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there any theorem which proves the decidability/undecidability of a recursive language being context free?

Comment: @user1892450:Actually,I haven't yet come across as such...but you can search if there is any by going through the NP-hard and NP-Complete problems section of your reading material....